# php find replace

Tags: php, str-replace

This is more of a "best practices" question.

I have a few email templates, that have several tags I need to find and replace.

For example:

```
Dear [[customername]],
Blah blah blah blah, and more blah.

Your Invoice....
----------------------------------------------------------
Order Status: [[orderstatus]]
Order Number: [[orderid]]
Date Ordered: [[dateordered]]
Payment Method: [[paymentmethod]]
Billing Statement: [[billingstatement]]
```

Anyway, I have several of these tags inside double brackets.
So I'm using a simple: $text = str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $text);

I'm sure this is the normal way to do this, but I am just curious if someone has thoughts on a different way.  Otherwise, I'll stick with what I'm doing.

Comment: In my opinion it's most efficient way of parsing templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arrays with str_replace:

```
$oldWords = array('[[customername]]',
                  '[[orderstatus]]'
                 );
$newWords = array($customerName,
                  $orderStatus
                 );

$newText = str_replace($oldWords , $newWords , $text);
```

You could also use preg_replace with an array

```
$oldWords = array('/\[\[customername\]\]/',
                  '/\[\[orderstatus\]\]/'
                 );
$newWords = array($customerName,
                  $orderStatus
                 );

$newText = preg_replace($oldWords , $newWords , $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure from your example, but if $oldWord and $newWord are strings (as their name indicates) then you're not doing it right. str_replace accepts array parameters so you can do all the replacements at once:

```
$text = str_replace($oldValues, $newValues, $text);
```

where $oldValues = array('[[customername]]', [[orderstatus]], ...)

and $newValues = array('John Smith', 'approved', ...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong for this as you said, i usualy name things:

```
_customername_
```

no particilar reason :)

Comment: I think he's looking at it from the code side, not the convention of differentiating variables in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array with str_replace

Answer (score 0):

I would say if your code is well formated the way you are doing it is ok, since it is the fastest way of doing it.

You could use also two arrays instead of two strings to pass to str_replace, but for my opinion this is less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension with Lexical analyser.
For tutorials on writing php extensions visit http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021 for example.

Comment: Yea because he struggles in PHP But thrives in C !

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would jsut create a small template class like so:

```
class EmailTemplate
{
    private $_template = '';

    public function __construct($template)
    {
        $this->_template = $template;
    }

    public function __set($key,$value)
    {
        $this->_template = str_replace("[[" . $key . "]]",$value,$this->_template);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->_template;
    }
}
```

and simple usage would be like so:

```
$temp = file_get_contents("email/templates/invoice.template");

$Template = new EmailTemplate($temp);

$Template->customername = "John Doe";
$Template->orderstatus = "On Route";
$Template->orderid = 14875356;
$Template->dateordered = date();
$Template->paymentmethod = "VISA (DD)";
$Template->billingstatement = "blah";

echo $Template; // = Happy.
```